# openLayers addFeature to a vectorsource from xmlhttprequest in angular

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, openlayers

I took insperation from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html where they use

```
   vectorSource.addFeatures(vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText));
```

but in angular using typescript addFeatures accepts Feature[]  while vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText) gives FeatureLike[].

> Argument of type 'FeatureLike[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Feature[]'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Feature[]'.ts(2345)

heres the section which errors:

```
     xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        source.addFeatures(
                            source
                                .getFormat()
                                ?.readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                        );
                    } else {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                };
```

is there a way to transform/cast FeatureLike to ordinary Feature, or maybe I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution to transform the data by using GeoJSON first (ref:[How to reference another answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277839/how-to-reference-another-answer))

```
  xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        let features = new GeoJSON({
                            featureProjection: 'EPSG:32633',
                        }).readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
                        source.addFeatures(features);
                    } else {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                };
```